# ABNORMAL_EXIT ошибки нет в интерпретаторе, не понимаю суть

Tags: python, python-3.x

В письменности языка НРЗБРЧВ отсутствуют гласные буквы и знаки препинания, в остальном язык ничем не отличается от русского языка. Чтобы из слова русского языка получить слово языка НРЗБРЧВ, достаточно выкинуть из слова все гласные. Чтобы перевести предложение, нужно перевести каждое слово и выкинуть знаки препинания. Регистр букв следует оставить неизменным.
Напишите функцию translate(text), которая переводит текст с русского языка на НРЗБРЧВ.
Свой результат функция должна записать во внешнюю переменную translated_text.
Вот мой код:

```
def translate(text):
    global translated_text
    vowels = ["А", "О", "У", "И", "Э", "Ы", "а", "о", "у," "и", "э", "ы"]
    punct_marks = [".", '?', ';', ":", '-', '(', ')', "'", "!"]
    text1 = list(text)
    if len(text1) >= 1:
        for i in text1:
            if i in vowels:
                text1.remove(i)
            elif i in punct_marks:
                text1.remove(i)
        translated_text = ' '.join(text1)
        print(f'translated_text == "{translated_text}"')
     print('')
```

Выдает ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/temp/executing/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(solution.translated_text)
AttributeError: module 'solution' has no attribute 'translated_text'
make: *** [run] Error 1
Completion status: ABNORMAL_EXIT
```

Я не понимаю в чем она

Comment: где у вас весь код? вы приводите ошибку с строке print(solution.translated_text), ее нет в примере

Answer (score 2):

Я так понимаю, ваш код тестирует автоматизированная система. Вот эта странная проверка `if len(text1) >= 1:` в случае, если она не выполнится, у вас не будет ничего в переменной `translated_text`, возможно поэтому и ошибка. Попробуйте присвоить хотя бы `translated_text = text` сразу после объявления глобальной переменной в начале функции.

Но это ещё не всё. Из-за того, что вы делаете `remove` прямо из списка, по которому итерируетесь, у вас возможно будут удалены не все символы, которые нужно удалить. Для начала можете попробовать итерироваться по копии списка:

```
for i in text1.copy():
```

И я не понял, почему вы деляете `join` через пробел, в условии задачи нет пробелов между буквами в результате:

```
translated_text = ' '.join(text1)
```

Делайте `''.join()`.

А вообще лучше эту задачу сделать через *списковое сокращение* - так будет проще, правильнее и понятнее. И основной код будет буквально в одну строку.